# Xcode character encoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, emoji

How do i turn the following into an emoji smiley face?

```
\uD83D\uDE04
```

According to [Unicode Wiki](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f604/index.htm), that is a "C/C++/Java source code". However when I save that as a NSLabel it just does exactly that. The text is \uD83D\uDE04 and not the emoji expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code sample. It will help you.

```
NSString *str = @"\uD83D\uDE04";

NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *valueUnicode = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSData *dataa = [valueUnicode dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *valueEmoj = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataa encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];

uiTextLable.text = valueEmoj;
```